# JCR SQL2 compare properties on same node

Tags: aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

We have some nodes with incorrect properties where cq:title does not equal cq:summary (we want these to always equal). To find them I type:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE s.[cq:title] <> s.[cq:summary]
```

I get the error:

```
expected: static operand
```

I read that we cannot compare properties under the same node.  I need a workaround please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest writing a small servlet that iterates over all pages and does the comparision on JCR property level.

Using a recursive methode this is rather easy to acomplish, just resolve the root from where you want to check and call the method:

```
private void checkChildren(Page parent) {
    Iterator<Page> children = parent.listChildren();
    while (children.hasNext()) {
        Page child = children.next();
        ValueMap props = child.getProperties();
        String title = props.get("jcr:title", String.class);
        String summary = props.get("jcr:summary", String.class);
        if (title != null && summary!=null && !title.equals(summary)) {
            //do something with it
        }
        checkChildren(child);
    }
}
```